# Mysql make column in table user specific

Tags: mysql, kodi

I would like to give a little background. I use Kodi which is set up to use my MySQL Server for storing all it needs to remember.
There is one table that stores the physical file location together with a flag whether that file was watched before or not.

I now want to share my DB with my family but I don't want them to have the same "seen" flags as I have. They should be able to store their own values.
I don't want to set up a separate MySQL Server for each of them and I would like to avoid making changes to the Kodi Code.

So is there a way I can make this column like a link that changes depending on the user that has logged in? So that the MySQL Query for Kodi keeps the same but the answer from the Server differs, depending on the user account?

Or are there any other ways you would accomplish this?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that helped. In one of the threads you linked I found the neccessary mysql commands for me :)

Comment: I am please to hear it helped, can you share the necessary MySQL command for future readers of this question?